# Estimation of $\int_{1/2}^1 f(x)dx$ when $f '(x) = \frac{192x^3}{2+\sin^4(\pi x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Question: $f '(x) = \frac{192x^3}{2+\sin^4(\pi x)}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(1/2)=0$. If $m\le\int_{1/2}^1 f(x) dx \le M$, then the possible values of $m$ and $M$ are....

Answer: $m=1$ and $M=12$

Solution: $f '(x)$ is increasing from $x= 1/2$ to $x=1$.

$f '(1/2) = 8$, $f '(1) = 96$

Hence $8 \lt f '(x) \lt 96$

$8 \lt \frac{f(1)-f(1/2)}{1- 1/2} \lt 96$

$8 \lt 2f(1) \lt 96$

$4 \lt f(1) \lt 48$

$1 \lt \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) dx \lt 12$

I understand $\int_{1/2}^1 f(x)dx \lt 12$ but not $1 \lt \int_{1/2}^1 f(x)dx$. Since $f '(x)$ is increasing, $f(x)$ is concave upward from $f(1/2)=0$ to $f(1)$. So isn't the minimum value of $\int_{1/2}^1 f(x)dx \lt 1$ when $f(1)=4$. That is the area under the diagonal of rectangle area $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4 = 2$ which is $1$.

Thanks.

Edit: Is this method correct, particularly, taking $1 \lt\int_{1/2}^1 f(x)dx \lt 12$ after $4 \lt f(1) \lt 48$ ?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/721644)

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in\left(\frac 12, 1\right]$. By the mean value theorem
$$\frac{f(x)-f\left(\frac 12\right)}{x-\frac 12}=f'(c_x)\\\Rightarrow
f(x)=f'(c_x)\left(x-\frac 12\right) $$
for some $c_x\in\left(\frac 12, x\right)$. As you noted, $8<f'(x)<96$ for $x\in\left(\frac 12, 1\right)$. Thus,
$$8\left(x-\frac 12\right)<f(x)<96\left(x-\frac 12\right) $$
for $x\in\left(\frac 12, 1\right]$. Integrating this gives
$$1=\int_{1/2}^18\left(x-\frac 12\right)\,dx<\int_{1/2}^1f(x)\,dx<
\int_{1/2}^196\left(x-\frac 12\right)\,dx=12 $$

---

What you've done is not sufficient to obtain the desired estimates. $f(1)<48$ together with $f$ being an increasing function for $x>0$ implies that $\int_{1/2}^1f(x)\,dx<\int_{1/2}^1 48\,dx=24$ which isn't sharp enough. And I haven't seen anything in your work to justify the lower bound.